# How to get Fire TV Device name like Fire TV Stick - 2nd Gen

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I need to device name of Firetv like "Fire TV Stick - 2nd Gen"

I am using below code for getting device name.

```
String AMAZON_MODEL = Build.MODEL;
if (AMAZON_MODEL.matches("AFTN")) {
 Log.v(TAG, "Yes, this is a Fire TV 3rd Gen device");
} else if(AMAZON_MODEL.matches("AFTT"){
 Log.v(TAG, "Yes, this is a Fire TV Stick - 2nd Gen");
}
```

But there are lot of device and model and in feature may be device name or model will increase so we can't use above logic.
How to get device  name by generic method like androidTV.

Comment: You will need to create an own list of ids and actual names. You can't get the full name from the device itself.